# PHP - Format array via Date.

Tags: php, arrays

I have a query that joins 2 tables:

```
$query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        p.patient_id,
        mh.reading_time, 
        mh.reading_value, 
        mh.fasting, 
        DATE(mh.date_added) AS date_added 
    FROM wmx_patient p 
    LEFT JOIN wmx_monitor_history mh 
        ON(p.patient_id = mh.patient_id) 
    WHERE p.access_token = '" . $this->db->escape($token) . "' 
    ORDER BY date_added DESC
");
```

This returns the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [patient_id] => 1
            [reading_time] => 02:12:19
            [reading_value] => 77
            [fasting] => 1
            [date_added] => 2014-04-21
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [patient_id] => 1
            [reading_time] => 18:45:00
            [reading_value] => 73
            [fasting] => 0
            [date_added] => 2014-04-17
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [patient_id] => 1
            [reading_time] => 04:31:00
            [reading_value] => 88
            [fasting] => 1
            [date_added] => 2014-04-17
        )

    ... 
)
```

I need to then combine those arrays by the `date_added` field so they look like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2014-04-21
            [readings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [time] => 2:12 AM
                            [reading] => 77
                            [fasting] => Yes
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2014-04-17
            [readings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [time] => 6:45 PM
                            [reading] => 73
                            [fasting] => No
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [time] => 4:31 AM
                            [reading] => 88
                            [fasting] => Yes
                        )

                )

        )

    ...

)
```

The loop I have now is clearly wrong as it adds all readings incrementally:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($query->rows as $i => $row):

    $child[] = array(
        'time'    => date('g:i A', strtotime($row['reading_time'])),
        'reading' => $row['reading_value'],
        'fasting' => $row['fasting'] ? 'Yes' : 'No' 
    );

    if (!in_array($row['date_added'], $data)):
        $data[] = array(
            'date'      => $row['date_added'],
            'readings'  => $child
        );
    endif;

endforeach;
```

I know I need to test somehow to see if the `date_added` is in the child array but I'm lost as to how.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the original array structure at all? Can't you simply store received rows in the desired format?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  I can't alter the database structure if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($query->fetch() as $row) {
  array_push($row, array('date' => $date_for_this_row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($query->rows as $i => $row):

    $child[] = array(
        'time'    => date('g:i A', strtotime($row['reading_time'])),
        'reading' => $row['reading_value'],
        'fasting' => $row['fasting'] ? 'Yes' : 'No' 
    );

    if ( !isset($data[$row['date_added']]) ):
        $data[$row['date_added']] = array(); // creat new array at that date

    endif;
    $data[$row['date_added']][] = $child; // add new reading item to the date array

endforeach;
```

actually that gives you a little different array:

```
Array (
    [2014-04-17] => Array
                    (
                      [0] => Array (  [time] => 2:12 AM
                                      [reading] => 77
                                      [fasting] => Yes
                                    ),
                      [1] => Array (  [time] => 4:12 AM
                                      [reading] => 63
                                      [fasting] => Yes
                                    ),
                      ...

    [2014-04-18] => Array
                    (
                      [0] => Array (  [time] => 2:12 AM
                                      [reading] => 77
                                      [fasting] => Yes
                                    ),
                      [1] => Array (  [time] => 4:12 AM
                                      [reading] => 63
                                      [fasting] => Yes
                                    ),
                      ...
    ...
```

which the can be handled by a foreach like:

```
   foreach ( $data as $date => $readings )
       foreach ( $readings as $reading )
          echo "on " . $date . " at " . $reading['time'] . " we got " . $reading['reading'];
```

Comment: Yeah this seems like it does basically the same thing, each date entry is getting all possible readings entered.  There must be some sort of group by clause that will group my query by date no?

Comment: No, sorry. tThe above code (not tested) _should_ group all readings by date

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
$data = array();
$children = array();
foreach($query->rows as $row):
    if (!$this->in_array_m($row['date_added'], $data)):
        $data[] = array(
            'date' => $row['date_added']
        );
    endif;

    $children[] = array(
        'time'       => date('g:i A', strtotime($row['reading_time'])),
        'reading'    => $row['reading_value'],
        'fasting'    => $row['fasting'] ? 'Yes' : 'No',
        'date_added' => $row['date_added']
    );

endforeach;

foreach ($data as $key => $value):
    foreach ($children as $child):
        if ($child['date_added'] == $value['date']):
            $data[$key]['readings'][] = $child;
        endif;
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Which is sort of a variation of Axel's answer.